# Pandas - KeyError: 'Styler.apply and '.applymap' are not compatible with non-unique index or columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a problem when apply style to Pandas Dataframe after pivot_table.

Follow my example of table after pivot_table
[Pre style apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbGp0.png)

when I apply the style
`df.style.applymap(style_negative, props='color:red;').to_html()`

KeyError: '`Styler.apply` and `.applymap` are not compatible with non-unique index or columns.'

Comment: What is `print (df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])` and `print (df.index[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)])`

Comment: first -> Index([], dtype='object', name='Data')

Comment: second -> MultiIndex([], names=['IdS', 'IdC'])

Comment: Thanks @jezrael
I actually had duplicate columns

Answer (score 0):

I solved,
I actually had duplicate columns,
verified with the command

```
print (df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])
```

Answer (score 0):

But the error could result of duplicate indices as stated in the message and can be prevented with

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```